# Julia: Is there a way to enumerate all matrices of size m by n with entries from a discrete set?

Tags: performance, matrix, julia, permutation

I am working with a set of functions of two variables f(x,y) in a 2D-grid. The function itself in each point in the grid can only take values from a finite set. I need to enumerate all possible functions that I can construct.

In particular, a function is defined as a matrix where the ith jth element tells me the value of the function evaluated at x_i, y_j.

I want to be able to create all the matrices possible. I know the total number of such matrices is nf^(nx*ny) where nf is the number of values that the function can take in a point, and nx, ny are the number of points in the grid of x and y. So, my tests will be with a modest number of grid points.

Thank you

I tried to express the problem as enumerating all branches in a tree and using recursion, but couldnt create a matrix as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you want?

```
function funs(fs)
    nf = length(fs)
    @assert length(unique(size.(fs))) == 1
    nx,ny = size(fs[1])
    sigs = Iterators.product(ntuple(i -> 1:nf, nx*ny)...)
    ([fs[sig[i+(j-1)*nx]][nx,ny] for i in 1:nx, j in 1:ny] for sig in sigs)
end
```

I am returning a generator that you can easily iterate over without materializing as collecting it might use too much memory. Of course for small data you can `collect` it with the additional benefit that it will be a `nx*ny` dimensional array allowing you to easily slice over the varying dimensions.

Here is an example:

```
julia> fs = [fill(1,2,2), fill(2,2,2), fill(3,2,2)]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,2},1}:
 [1 1; 1 1]
 [2 2; 2 2]
 [3 3; 3 3]

julia> funs(fs)
Base.Generator{Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{NTuple{4,UnitRange{Int64}}},getfield(Main, Symbol("##46#49")){Array{Array{Int64,2},1},Int64,Int64}}(getfield(Main, Symbol("##46#49")){Array{Array{Int64,2},1},Int64,Int64}(Array{Int64,2}[[1 1; 1 1], [2 2; 2 2], [3 3; 3 3]], 2, 2), Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{NTuple{4,UnitRange{Int64}}}((1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)))

julia> collect(funs(fs))
3×3×3×3 Array{Array{Int64,2},4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 [1 1; 1 1]  [1 1; 2 1]  [1 1; 3 1]
 [2 1; 1 1]  [2 1; 2 1]  [2 1; 3 1]
 [3 1; 1 1]  [3 1; 2 1]  [3 1; 3 1]

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 [1 2; 1 1]  [1 2; 2 1]  [1 2; 3 1]
 [2 2; 1 1]  [2 2; 2 1]  [2 2; 3 1]
 [3 2; 1 1]  [3 2; 2 1]  [3 2; 3 1]

[:, :, 3, 1] =
 [1 3; 1 1]  [1 3; 2 1]  [1 3; 3 1]
 [2 3; 1 1]  [2 3; 2 1]  [2 3; 3 1]
 [3 3; 1 1]  [3 3; 2 1]  [3 3; 3 1]

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 [1 1; 1 2]  [1 1; 2 2]  [1 1; 3 2]
 [2 1; 1 2]  [2 1; 2 2]  [2 1; 3 2]
 [3 1; 1 2]  [3 1; 2 2]  [3 1; 3 2]

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 [1 2; 1 2]  [1 2; 2 2]  [1 2; 3 2]
 [2 2; 1 2]  [2 2; 2 2]  [2 2; 3 2]
 [3 2; 1 2]  [3 2; 2 2]  [3 2; 3 2]

[:, :, 3, 2] =
 [1 3; 1 2]  [1 3; 2 2]  [1 3; 3 2]
 [2 3; 1 2]  [2 3; 2 2]  [2 3; 3 2]
 [3 3; 1 2]  [3 3; 2 2]  [3 3; 3 2]

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 [1 1; 1 3]  [1 1; 2 3]  [1 1; 3 3]
 [2 1; 1 3]  [2 1; 2 3]  [2 1; 3 3]
 [3 1; 1 3]  [3 1; 2 3]  [3 1; 3 3]

[:, :, 2, 3] =
 [1 2; 1 3]  [1 2; 2 3]  [1 2; 3 3]
 [2 2; 1 3]  [2 2; 2 3]  [2 2; 3 3]
 [3 2; 1 3]  [3 2; 2 3]  [3 2; 3 3]

[:, :, 3, 3] =
 [1 3; 1 3]  [1 3; 2 3]  [1 3; 3 3]
 [2 3; 1 3]  [2 3; 2 3]  [2 3; 3 3]
 [3 3; 1 3]  [3 3; 2 3]  [3 3; 3 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I understand from OP:

```
function all_functions(finite_set, nx, ny)
  I = Iterators.product(fill(finite_set, nx*ny)...)
  (reshape(collect(i), (nx,ny)) for i in I)
end
```

and in action:

```
julia>fs = (0,1,2,3)
julia>collect(Iterators.take(all_functions(fs, 2, 2), 8))
Array{Int64,2}[[0 0; 0 0], [1 0; 0 0], [2 0; 0 0], [3 0; 0 0], [0 0; 1 0], [1 0; 1 0], [2 0; 1 0], [3 0; 1 0]]
```